# Laurent series expansion, can one simplify this?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have to expand $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{(z^2+1)z}$ in an annulus $R(i,1,2)$.

---

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-i}\frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{1}{z-i}\Big(\frac{i}{z+i}-\frac{i}{z}\Big)$$

---

$$\frac{1}{z-i}\frac{1}{z+i}=\frac{1}{z-i}\cdot\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-(z-i)/2i)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (\frac{1}{2i})^{n+1}(z-i)^n$$

---

$$\frac{i}{z+i}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-(-(z-i)/2i)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (\frac{1}{2i})^{n}\frac{1}{2}(z-i)^n$$

---

$$\frac{i}{z}=\frac{i}{z-i}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-i/(z-i))}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n i^{n+1}(\frac{1}{z-i})^{n+1}$$

---

Finally we got:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (\frac{1}{2i})^{n+1}(z-i)^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (\frac{1}{2i})^{n+1}(z-i)^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n i^{n+1}(\frac{1}{z-i})^{n+2}=\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{z-i}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big( (-1)^{n-1}(\frac{1}{2i})^{n}-(-1)^n (\frac{1}{2i})^{n+1}\Big)(z-i)^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n i^{n+1}(\frac{1}{z-i})^{n+2}$$

My questions are: is this expansion correct? And can one simplify it?

Comment: What does $R(i,1,2)$ mean?

Comment: annulus centered at $i$ with $r=1$ and $R=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From partial fractions, we have that
$$
f(z) = \frac{-1}{z} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1+i}{z+i} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1-i}{z-i}
$$

For the Laurent series in annulus, I obtained:
\begin{align}
\frac{-1}{z} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1+i}{z+i} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1-i}{z-i}
&= \frac{-1}{z-i}\frac{1}{1+\bigl(\frac{i}{z-i}\bigr)} + \frac{1}{4i}\frac{1+i}{1+\bigl(\frac{z -i}{2i}\bigr)}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-i}{z-i}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1-i}{z-i}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\biggl[i^n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(z-i)^{n+1}}+\frac{1+i}{4i}\Bigl(\frac{i}{2}\Bigr)^n(z-i)^n\biggr]
\end{align}
I checked the results on Mathematica as well and it checked out. However, Wolfram online wouldn't compute it, so I attached a screen shot of my results.
[image]

Comment: So my result is incorrect?

Comment: @luka5z I had trouble following it since you didn't decompose the fractions fully.

Comment: Could you type my result in mathematica and check if it is correct? I Would be very grateful... If its too much work dont do it, though

Comment: @luka5z you result doesn't produce $\frac{z-1}{z(z^2+1)}$

Answer (score 0):

Hi this series as generalitation of Laurent Series in  three poles
$$\sum _{k=-1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \left((-i)^k-i i^k\right) x^k+\frac{(-1)^{n-1} \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) x^{n+1}\right)}{x-i}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1} \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) x^{n+1}\right)}{x+i}$$